# I want to choose the particular column of the last inserted record. How can I do that?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
select max(created_t) from inv_database  ;
```

**o/p** = `78578596`

```
select in_date from inv_database where created_t = 78578596;
```

I want to merge these two queries and want the result.
There are 4 records which have maximum `created_t` and all of them have  same `in_date`.I want to get that date. what query it will need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select in_date
from inv_database
where created_t = (select max(created_t) from inv_database);
```

You could also use an analytic function like `row_number`:

```
select t.in_date
from
(
    select in_date,
        row_number() over (order by created_t desc) rn
    from inv_database
) t
where t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Note that these queries can give different results - which is correct will depend on the actual requirements and whether the dependency of `in_date` -> `created_t` is constrained or not.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Yes there is an issue of what would happen with ties.

Answer (score 0):

SubQuery will help you...

```
select in_date as Date
from inv_database
where created_t 
= (select max(created_t) from inv_database);
```

you can try it based on your table column structure.